# bash: return code from redirected input command

Tags: mysql, bash, io-redirection, return-code

I have a bash script I am using to loop through and process the results from a SQL query like such.

```
while read field1 field2 field3 field4
do
    {...something here...}
done < <(mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p"$PASS" $DB << EOF
 {...multi-line select query here...}
EOF)
```

The problem I do not know how to solve is how do I refactor this so I can get the return code, error out and skip the loop if something goes wrong querying the database?

Edit:

I have tried to using a named-pipe with the following.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p"$PASS" $DB << EOF >> /tmp/mypipe
  {...multi-line select query here...}
EOF
echo $?
{...loop here...}
```

This did not seem to work because the mysql command sits and waits for the pipe to be read before continuing. So unless I have something reading the pipe mysql does not exit to have a return code.

I have tried storing the query results into a variable first with the following.

```
DATADUMP=$(mysql -h $HOST -u $USER -p"$PASS" $DB -e \
  'select stuff from place \
  join table 1 on record ..... \
  ')
```

The issue I ran into with this is the read loop would only read the first four "words" from the DATADUMP variable and would ignore the rest.

At this point, unless someone comes back with a great idea, I'm going to mktemp a temp file to hold the query results. I was hoping to keep from constantly reading and writing to the disk, but my deadline is approaching very quickly.

Comment: When `mysql` fails do you get any output that the loop sees? That is are you only interested in the case where the loop never runs? Or can you get partial data but still have the command fail that you need to catch? If the latter (or you want the return code specifically and not just "it failed") then you may need to use a fifo so you can separately run mysql and write to it and then read from it later (or something like that).

Comment: I would say then, just "skipping" might not be enough. As long as consistency matters and it's not about DDL, do transactions. Also, it might happen that bash isn't a best choice for that. Like: combine queries into file (with transactions handling if possible) and then execute.

Comment: When mysql fails, whatever its output is gets processed by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is no convenient way to do this, other than to capture the entire output of the `mysql` command before processing it. You could capture it into a variable, if you thought it wasn't going to be gigabytes of data, or into a temporary file. That's the only way to guarantee that no partial result is processed in the case of an error.

If you knew that all errors produced empty output, then it would be reasonably simple, since the `while` loop wouldn't execute at all. You wouldn't be able to distinguish between an error and an empty search, but you could work around that by producing an error indication:

```
got_data=0
while read field1 field2; do
  got_data=1
  # ...
done < <( mysql ... || printf "%s %d" "ERROR" $?) <<EOF
  # ...
EOF
)
if ((!got_data)); then
  if [[ $field1 == "ERROR" ]]; then
    # error code is in $field2
  else
    # query returned no result
fi
```

However, the premise is likely to be false. In particular, a network failure in the middle of the query return will probably produce both some output and an error indication. And in that case, the above code would process the partial return.

If you don't actually mind processing a partial result, as long as the error is eventually detected, then you could use a simple variation on the above code. The code guarantees that an unsuccessful exit of `mysql` will eventually produce a line which starts with the `ERROR` token. (I don't know if `mysql` guarantees output of a trailing newline if the network transmission is interrupted. You'd need to play some games to guarantee that the error line output by `printf` always appeared on a line by itself.)

There is a little trick in the above: The error line (`ERROR 3`, for example) is output with `printf` *without a trailing newline*. The absence of the trailing newline will cause `read` to exit with a failure code even though it will successfully split the line into the variables `field1` and `field2`. This makes it unnecessary to try to distinguish the error indication from normal data inside the `while` loop, although you still need a clear indication for the test after the `while` loop.